# Vaadin 14 LoginPage adds a request to /error but why

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, vaadin14

I am working on a spring boot Webapp with Vaadin 14 with JDK 11.
I am using the stadard login form. And i have a custom request cache. I did not change anything at the code of the webapp or its dependencies or the java version.

The error that i get seems to come from the mechanic of sending unauthorized users to the login page.

But with the new version this does not work anymore. I hope somebody has this issue as well. I dont know why this behaviour is now happening.

At the start the user opens the browser with https://localhost:8101/application and the system recognizes that he is not authenticated yet and sends him to the login view. But before entering anything. The system adds a request to /error and overwrites the inital /application target. So after entering valid credentials, the user will see this error page:
timestamp   "2023-11-21T16:39:00.602+00:00"
status  999
error   "None"

After googling about this strange error i found this, but i am not using Keycloak at all: https://github.com/vaadin/collaboration-engine/issues/41
But the error seems to be the same.

Here is a part of my log file:

```
    c.m.w.s.CustomRequestCache     | saveRequest          | 75  | Saved request https://localhost:8101/application to session
    .s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy | sendRedirect         | 57  | Redirecting to https://localhost:8101/login
    ssionSecurityContextRepository | saveContext          | 357 | Did not store empty SecurityContext
    ssionSecurityContextRepository | saveContext          | 357 | Did not store empty SecurityContext
    curityContextPersistenceFilter | doFilter             | 120 | Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
    o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy       | doFilterInternal     | 218 | Securing GET /login
    .w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter | doFilter             | 127 | Request: filter invocation [GET /login]; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
    curityContextPersistenceFilter | doFilter             | 104 | Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
    .AnonymousAuthenticationFilter | doFilter             | 100 | Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
    .a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor | beforeInvocation     | 210 | Authorized filter invocation [GET /login] with attributes [permitAll]
    o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy       | doFilter             | 333 | Secured GET /login
    DefaultDeploymentConfiguration | logMessages          | 154 | Vaadin is running in production mode.
    c.v.f.s.c.PushRequestHandler   | <init>               | 102 | Using pre-initialized Atmosphere for servlet springServlet
    c.v.f.s.SpringInstantiator     | getI18NProvider      | 81  | The number of beans implementing 'I18NProvider' is 0. Cannot use Spring beans for I18N, falling back to the default behavior
    c.v.f.s.c.UidlWriter           | createUidl           | 164 | * Creating response to client
    c.v.f.s.BootstrapHandler       | getInitialUidl       | 797 | Initial UIDL: [object Object]
    ssionSecurityContextRepository | saveContext          | 360 | Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
    ssionSecurityContextRepository | saveContext          | 360 | Did not store anonymous SecurityContext
    curityContextPersistenceFilter | doFilter             | 120 | Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
    o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy       | doFilterInternal     | 218 | Securing GET /error
    .w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter | doFilter             | 127 | Request: filter invocation [GET /error]; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
    curityContextPersistenceFilter | doFilter             | 104 | Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
    .AnonymousAuthenticationFilter | doFilter             | 100 | Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
    .a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor | attemptAuthorization | 247 | Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /error] with attributes [authenticated]
    c.m.w.s.CustomRequestCache     | saveRequest          | 75  | Saved request https://localhost:8101/error to session
    .s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy | sendRedirect         | 57  | Redirecting to https://localhost:8101/login
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by not allowing request with the word error to enter the cache:

```
    if (!com.app.security.SecurityUtils.isFrameworkInternalRequest(request) &&
            !request.getServletPath().contains("error")) {
        super.saveRequest(request, response);
    }
```

I did not find the source of this, but i fought the symptoms of it.